# Looking for easy example of 2-dimensional Noetherian domain which is not Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension, cohen-macaulay

I am looking for an easy example , with proof, of a 2-dimensional Noetherian domain which is not Cohen-Macaulay .

I know and it is easy to prove that such an example doesn't exist in dimension 1. But in dimension 2 such examples exist, but I don't know of any.

Please help.

Comment: $K[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$.

Comment: @user26857 : could you please elaborate on why is it 2 dimensional and not Cohen-Macaulay ?

Comment: For details see [here](https://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/minicourses/algebra/spiroff1.pdf).